# Java Classes used in the Polopoly CMS system, and Velocity templating language

Tags: java, velocity

I'm in a rather unenviable position: I need to find out how to create templates in the Polopoly Content Management System to display news stories, queues of stories etc.

I have no documentation, the the guy who usually deals with this is away. I have little experience of Java, but the project manager has assigned me to this anyway (I have xp in the .NET framework, C#, HTML, CSS, Javascript and jQuery, and a good grasp of OOP for what it's worth, but not Apache, Tomcat, Ant or any of the stuff used in the Polopoly back end).

I have access to a test system where I can tinker around a bit.

Can anyone point me in the direction fo any useful books, online resources or anything that can help me understand how the Polopoly/Java/Velocity stuff works together? Or give me some idea of where to start with this?

I cannot seem to find much by Googling, the Velocity guidegives me an idea of how Velocity works, but not the objects/classes used by Polopoly.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to know is a background in

1. Java to write some Controllers, if mandatory
2. XML to create templates
3. Velocity/Jquery/Java/Flash to write output

on support.polopoly.com you will find some points ...

It is a proprietary system and the documents are not a good intro.
You need some time ...

Feed your brain with model - content
                     view -  velocity, jquery, ...
                     control -xml, java

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

What you need is access to support.polopoly.com. There you can find the Developer Guide, JavaDoc, How Tos and more. You can also report support issues and request help from Professional Services on that site. Basically, a one-stop-shop for Polopoly stuff!

Hope that helps!

Best regards,
Mattias

Comment: Thanks Mattias, will endeavour to get myself a login :)